# How can inheritance be applied to a group of classes once

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

In c#, I would like the abstract class to be applied to many other classes. How can I do it without marking each class.

```
public abstract class Bar
{
 public bool Blah { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Bar
{
 public int FooId { get; set; }
}

public class Stool : Bar {}
public class Fun : Bar {}
public class NoFun : Bar {}
```

etc, etc.

Is there a way to just grab every class and then mark it as inheriting `Bar`?

Comment: I don't understand. How do you specify which classes you want to be inherited from `Bar`? Surely not all of them in the assembly.

Comment: @root45 - All in the namespace, or all in a list. Not sure how it would work hence the question :)

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is generics somehow. But you'd still have to change the class definitions for all existing classes which is exactly what you don't want. Maybe you'll have to look for a tool to automate that or use templating to create your classes.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - I was kind of hoping there was some awesome way to use generics or reflection to do this, but I guess not :(

Comment: Are you using code generation? If so you can modify the default T4 templates. [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: @amit_g - No, I am not using code generation. That is a good suggestion though and I have read good things about code generation and T4 templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You could have a visual studio add-in that did this, or some other similar sort of static code manipulation tool, but in terms of the language itself there is no way to modify the inheritance of a type at runtime, and as far as I know of no existing visual studio functionality for doing this for you.

Comment: Dang, so I am stuck copy pasting `: Bar` on a bunch of classes. :( I hate copy paste, it is evil.

Comment: Well, you could improve your overall design such that you don't *need* to have a whole lot of classes all with the same base class.  We don't really know enough about your program to suggest how you might go about doing that.

Comment: A hah! lol, I almost put an excerpt of `why?!` but didn't want to complicate things. This inheritance will be used to support temporal  soft-delete / cascade restore for entities mapped in EF 4.1. Every class, and every table in the db, will need to have a couple of the same fields.

Comment: Can you have a method that takes a 'Table' and deletes it, rather than having each 'Table' know how to delete itself.  You will likely, no matter what you do, have to have each DB Table class either extend some common class or some common interface, but an interface might be prefereable (over an abstract class).  Are the DB table classes auto-generated code?  If so, put the abstract class in whatever auto-generates them.

Comment: Not really, no. The table doesn't know how to delete itself, the records know how to throw a flag up if they are deprecated. This allows for referential integrity to be maintained in a data deprecated environment. An interface will just be redundant in that it will define the contract for each class, and then I will still have to write out, in each class, the fields.

Comment: So how can the abstract class successfully delete each table?  Is there some abstract method that they're already defining, or some set of fields, etc. that the delete method needs?  Basically I assumed that whatever the abstract class used from the inherited class to do the delete could be put in the interface, and then some static utility method could do the delete.

Comment: The abstract class is merely adding in fields that I don't want to copy paste into each class, but that each class will share. There are no methods in the abstract class. Copy pasting `: Bar` is much nicer than copy pasting `field 1 {}, field 2{}, field 3{}, field 4{}, field 5{}`. You might want to look into Entity Framework, and ASP.NET MVC 3 some more for more generic implementation details and where that logic is usually placed.

Comment: Given both that you want to add data, and not functionality, and that you're plugging into a framework for which you can't control, there really are no preferable options that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using templates and/or a VS add-in as the other posters mentioned, it is technically possible to do this with Reflection.Emit, though it'd be quite laborious and probably not very performant. It could come down to IL manipulation and having to create a function that manually maps the IL from the base class onto the new dynamic type.

If you can use an interface instead of an abstract class that could be a bit easier. Here is some sample code to get you started either way:

```
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("MyDynamicAssembly");

    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly
        (assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

    ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule
        ("MyDynamicAssembly", "MyDynamicAssembly.dll");

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType
        ("MyDynamicAssembly." + typeName, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(object));

    typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IMyInterface)); 

    typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
```